# Summation from sub list

Tags: python, list, sublist

If n = 4, m = 3, I have to select 4 elements (basically n elements) from a list from start and end. From below example lists are [17,12,10,2] and [2,11,20,8].

Then between these two lists I have to select the highest value element and after this the element has to be deleted from the original list.

The above step has to be performed m times and take the summation of the highest value elements.

```
A = [17,12,10,2,7,2,11,20,8], n = 4, m = 3
```

O/P: 20+17+12=49

I have written the following code. However, the code performance is not good and giving time out for larger list. Could you please help?

```
A = [17,12,10,2,7,2,11,20,8]
m = 3
n = 4
scoreSum = 0
count = 0
firstGrp = []
lastGrp = []

while(count<m):
    firstGrp = A[:n]
    lastGrp = A[-n:]
    maxScore = max(max(firstGrp), max(lastGrp))

    scoreSum = scoreSum + maxScore
    if(maxScore in firstGrp):
        A.remove(maxScore)
    else:
        ai = len(score) - 1 - score[::-1].index(maxScore)
        A.pop(ai)
    count = count + 1

    firstGrp.clear()
    lastGrp.clear()
print(scoreSum )
```

Comment: How are you *selecting 4 elements (basically n elements) from a list from start and end*?

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles ? Please put a reproductible model that we can test and debug.

Comment: Isn't this the sum of the greatest *m* elements? e.g. `sum(sorted(A, reverse=True)[:3])`

Comment: @CristiFati I was talking the same. Regardless of what `n` is, output is sum of top `m` values. Or OP wants to make it clear on how `n` values are selected.

Comment: If the same number presents both the start and end lists, then lowest index should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do that this way, you can generalize it later:

```
a = [17,12,10,2,7,2,11,20,8]
a.sort(reverse=True)
sums=0
for i in range(3):
    sums +=a[i]
print(sums)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about performance, you should use specific libraries like numpy. This will be much faster !

Comment: for big arrays that's the way to go, yes

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [17,12,10,2,7,11,20,8]
n = 4
m = 3

score = 0

for _ in range(m):
  sublist = A[:n] + A[-n:]
  subidx = [x for x in range(n)] + [x for x in range(len(A) - n, len(A))]
  sub = zip(sublist, subidx)
  maxval = max(sub, key=lambda x: x[0])
  score += maxval[0]
  del A[maxval[1]]

print(score)
```

Your method uses a lot of max() calls. Combining the slices of the front and back lists allows you to reduce the amounts of those max() searches to one pass and then a second pass to find the index at which it occurs for removal from the list.

Comment: For the below input A = [18,5,15,18,11,15,9,7], n = 1, m = 5, O/P should be 60.

Comment: Oh you're correct. I'm modifying my solution to zip each value with its index into the sublist; this way each max value to remove will always have the index to remove at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this code is not giving correct output for A = [17,12,10,2,7,11,20,8], n = 4, m = 3 and answer should be 20+17+12=49, mentioned in my original post.